# get count of some data from a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, count

I have a datatable in a vb.net Project that it is filled from a stored procedure,
the data inside the dataTable is like the below:

```
Division        Department              Unit            ID
----------      ----------              ----------      -----
Division a      Business                Development     User 1              
Division a      Business                Development     User 1              
Division a      Business                Development     User 1              
Division a      Business                Development     User 1              
Division a      Business                Development     User 1              
Division a      Business                Development     User 1              
Division a      Business                Development     User 1              
Division a      Business                Development     User 1              
Division a      Business                Development     User 1              
Division a      Business                Development     User 1              
Division a      Business                Development     User 1              
Division a      Business                Management      User 2              
Division a      Business                Management      User 2              
Division a      Business                Management      User 2              
Division a      Business                Management      User 2              
Division a      Business                Management      User 2              
Division a      Business                Management      User 2              
Division a      Business                Management      User 2              
Division a      Business                Management      User 2              
Division a      Business                Management      User 2              
Division a      Business                Management      User 2              
Division a      Business Operations     Office Support  User 3                  
Division a      Business Operations     Office Support  User 3                  
Division a      Business Operations     Office Support  User 3
```

I want to compute the count of how many unit i have, and the occurrence of it

example:  here i have 3 units, (11 development, 10 management and 3 office support)

Comment: Take a look at the DataView class and the RowFilter property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Easy with `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
Dim unitGroups = From row In table.AsEnumerable()
                 Group row By unit = row.Field(Of String)("Unit") Into Group
                 Select unit = New With {.Name = unit, .Count = Group.Count()}
                 Order By unit.Count Descending
For Each grp In unitGroups
    Console.WriteLine("Unit: {0}  Count:{1}", grp.Name, grp.Count)
Next
```

The `Order By` is not needed, i wanted to show it anyway. If you want to know the number of units you just need:

```
Dim countUnits As Int32 = unitGroups.Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve is to do like this:

```
Dim distinctDT As DataTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "unit")
Msgbox(distinctDT.Rows.Count)
```

Where dt is your datatable